# How to kill/terminate 360 process on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, virus, anti-virus, installer

I wondering if it's possible to terminate [360 Total Security](https://www.360totalsecurity.com/en/features/360-total-security/) from command line on Windows.

I tried

```
pskill.exe QHSafeTray.exe
Unable to kill process
Access denied
```

Also tried `taskkill /f /im QHSafeTray.exe` and `taskkill /f /im QHSafeTray.exe /t` and  `Stop-Process -name QHSafeTray.exe`, all failed the same way.

Doing the above with an `Administrator` account.

Side question, is there another account on windows with higher powers that can do that?

To add a bit of context, I thinking to disable the anti-virus during the installation of an application because AV is interfering in the process. Not sure if that's a good approach though.

Comment: Likely no, as that would defeat the purpose of antivirus/anti-malware software - does it run as `SYSTEM` _(IIRC, antivirus/anti-malware runs as `System` to prevent this very thing from occurring - you don't want this type of security program to be able to killed by a user with Admin privileges, as that's easily exploitable. I may be misremembering, but I believe antivirus/anti-malware loads in the kernel)_.

Comment: If you open Process Explorer, look at the process details, under the Security tab, does it have a "Protected" value shown, e.g. PsProtectedSignerAntimalware-Light?  It maybe that the product has a tamper protection feature as well which is downgrading the access writes of the process opening a handle to the process.